# Creating a 3D terrain programmatically

Tags: python

I'm new to Blender and can't find an answer to my question anywhere. Before, I assume that it simply couldn't be done, but I'm asking now just to make sure:

Can I create a 3D Terrain with Google Maps programmatically, i.e. without using Blender GUI, and then add objects (cubes, etc..) based on data fetched from an API?

Comment: Yes you can. The simplest approach is to generate JSON data outside of Blender, and then operate on that data inside Blender.

Comment: There are also add-ons like [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) that can import geographic data.